# Index.ts not being generated

Tags: angular

I m generating a component but it wont generate index.ts file . I am using the following command

```
ng g c Databinding
```

whereas i am running windows with `node 6.9.1` and `angular-cli version 1.0.0 beta.20-4`
while my app.component.ts has following code

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { DatabindingComponent } from './databinding/databinding.component';
//./databinding/databinding.component is a replacement for ./databinding as     index.ts didn't generated. 
@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  template: `
  <h1>{{title}}</h1>
 <app-databinding></app-databinding>
  `,
  directives : [DatabindingComponent];
})
export class AppComponent {
    title = 'I changed it!';
}
```

Edit, Following on [Angular github](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/pull/1658), i found out that index.ts is not a part of angular generate, so my question is how to use directives now?

Answer (score 1):

The index.ts file inside the folder is used to exports the classes you want to show, like:

```
import { Component1, Component2 } from './databinding';
```

[They were removed from angular-cli](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/1585) since the [introduction of module](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/ngmodule.html#!#angular-modularity). It's now used to expose the API of your module (inside the app folder).